# How can I find an iframe when it doesn't have a name or id?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I'm making a selenium project and as a part  of it I need to login into an account on [www.allmovie.com](http://www.allmovie.com). I have noticed that when clicking on "log in" button it switches to an `iframe`. It is required that I use `driver.switchTo().frame()` for all `iframes` in the project, but I cant identify id, name  or an index for the login page. What can I do here?
 [login page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iUHl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iframe` like any other webelement can by located by id, class, tag, xpath, css etc., not just by id.
So that `iframe` can be located by following `css_selector` `iframe` since it's a unique tag name of that element.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe")));
```

Or with `//iframe` `xpath` selectror.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe")));
```

Comment: So what should I give as a parameter to "frame()"?

Comment: I have already wrote you a whole code line that will switch the driver to that iframe

Comment: `frame()` you mentioned receives a webElement parameter. This is exactly what `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe"))` returns

Comment: Yeah sorry, the code wasn't showing yet when I wrote that. The page still didn't change to the login frame, but thank you for the response anyway :)

Comment: Not really but your answer made me think in the direction that helped to resolve it, so I'll mark yours as the correct one

Answer (score 0):

add some waits and check
code snippet in Python Selenium

```
iframe = WebDriverWait(driver,2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body > div.login-modal > iframe")))
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```